# Creating macros with given condition, adding sheets

Tags: excel

[image: Sample Data]

Hi all, I need help with the following table. I have customer names in column J. Now I need to create new sheet with each customer name and copy all the related rows and columns with header for this particular customer. Also, as you can see under Customer_name, there are numbers or codes attached at the end. So i need to create new sheets(containing all the information about that customer) with following customer names as per given sample table
Sheet 1 - VCLD- 1610
Sheet 2 - VCLD- 1660
Sheet 3 - BVM 3002003
Sheet 4 - 30  (This sheet contains all the customers with codes starting with 30, i.e 30-32003,32090)
Sheet 5 - 30-32003
Sheet 6 - 30-32090

Can somebody help me out here, how to do it, using functions or macros. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You could probably use either `Vlookup()` or `Index/Match` to pull the relevant info in. What have you tried so far? Please show any code/formulas attempted.

Comment: Why is `30-*` arbitrarily different from `VCLD-*` or `BVM-*`?  You have separate sheets for `VCLD- 1610` and `VCLD- 1660`.  Suddenly trying to group `30-*` seems weird and unnecessary, especially when you have separate sheets for `30-32003` and `30-32090` immediately afterwards

Comment: Yes, the customer wants it that ways I know it's weird. These numbers represents some sub-branches so they wanna have a look on billing customer wise and branch wise. I just used the function Mid(=MID(J2,10,15)) to extract everything after 'Customer' in column J.

Comment: I don't care about BVM and VCLD much b'coz they are not that many...but i definitely wanna separate sheets based on 30 and it's constituents numbers..please help

Comment: Unless you want to manually create a sheet for each combination of customer / branch you'll probably have to use VBA to create a solution. Yet, you are surely aware that this website is not a free code-writing service. So, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. i know this is not a free code-writing service website. I am learning VBA and I wanted to fix this issue. Nevermind I'll do this task eventually. Just was looking for some help to get started. Thanks a lot.